# How to display all dates for multiple model annotations in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

So I'm working on a website, and I want to have some kind of a summary page to display the data that I have. Let's say I have these models:

```
class IceCream(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField()
    color = models.CharField()


class Cupcake(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField()
    icing = models.CharField()
```

So on this page, users will be able to input a date range for the summary. I'm using DRF to serialize the data and to display them on the view actions. After I receive the filter dates, I will filter out the IceCream objects and Cupcake objects using the created field from TimeStampedModel.

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
def dessert_summary(self, request, **kwargs):
    start_date = self.request.query_params.get('start_date')
    end_date = self.request.query_params.get('end_date')
    cupcakes = Cupcake.objects.filter(created__date__range=[start_date, end_date])
    ice_creams = IceCream.objects.filter(created__date__range=[start_date, end_date])
```

After filtering, I want to count the total cupcakes and the total ice creams that is created within that period of time. But I also want to group them by the dates, and display the total count for both ice creams and cupcakes based on that date. So I tried to annotate the querysets like this:

```
cupcakes = cupcakes.annotate(date=TruncDate('created'))
cupcakes = cupcakes.values('date')
cupcakes = cupcakes.annotate(total_cupcakes=Count('id'))
ice_creams = ice_creams.annotate(date=TruncDate('created'))
ice_creams = ice_creams.values('date')
ice_creams = ice_creams.annotate(total_ice_creams=Count('id'))
```

So I want the result to be something like this:

```
{
    'summary': [{
        'date': "2020-09-24",
        'total_ice_creams': 10,
        'total_cupcakes': 7,
        'total_dessert': 17
    }, {
        'date': "2020-09-25',
        'total_ice_creams': 6,
        'total_cupcakes': 5,
        'total_dessert': 11
    }]
}
```

But right now this is what I am getting:

```
{
    'summary': [{
        'cupcakes': [{
            'date': "2020-09-24",
            'total_cupcakes': 10,
        }, {
            'date': "2020-09-25",
            'total_cupcakes': 5,
        }],
        'ice_creams': [{
            'date': "2020-09-24",
            'total_ice_creams': 7,
        }, {
            'date': "2020-09-27",
            'total_ice_creams': 6,
        }]
    }]
}
```

What I want to ask is how do I get all the dates of both querysets, sum the ice creams and cupcakes, and return the data like the expected result? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what you can do:

- gather all icecream/cupcakes count data into a dictionary

```
icecream_dict = {obj['date']: obj['count'] for obj in ice_creams}
cupcakes_dict = {obj['date']: obj['count'] for obj in cupcakes}
```

- create a sorted list with all the dates

```
all_dates = sorted(set(list(icecream_dict.keys()) + list(cupcakes_dict.keys())))
```

- create a list with items for each date and their count

```
result = []
for each_date in all_dates:                                                                                                                                                                               
    total_ice_creams = icecream_dict.get(each_date, 0)                                                                                                                                                                 
    total_cupcakes = cupcakes_dict.get(each_date, 0)                                                                                                                                                                 
    res = {
        'date': each_date, 
        'total_ice_creams': total_ice_creams, 
        'total_cupcakes': total_cupcakes, 
        'total_dessert': total_ice_creams + total_cupcakes
    }                                                                                                   
    result.append(res)

# check the result
print(result)
```

**Hint**: If you plan to add more desert-like models, consider have a base model `Desert` that you could query directly instead of querying each desert type model.

Comment: Hi! I forgot there is a dictionary comprehension as well. Thank you so much for your answer, this is what I have been looking for!